# Modify Type Name in Linq2DB Templates Generation

Tags: sql-server, t4, linq2db

I'm trying to scaffold an existing database using the LinqToDB templates.  All of the tables in the database have a prefix of "tbl", i.e "tblPerson".  I would like to strip this (and other prefixes) from my type names.  I tried modifying the DataModel.ttinclude file in the LinqToDB.Templates directory but it doesn't seem to have any affect.

```
TypeName = t.TypeName.StartsWith("Tbl") ? t.TypeName.Replace("Tbl","") : t.TypeName,
```

Clearly I'm missing something simple.

Comment: Check customization section to see how to modify generation model https://linq2db.github.io/articles/T4.html#example-of-generation-process-customization

Comment: Thanks, that helped!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the link from DLuk, I was able to modify the tables using the following code in my DB.tt file.

```
foreach (var t in Tables.Values)
{
    t.TypeName = t.TypeName.StartsWith("Tbl") ? t.TypeName.Replace("Tbl","") : t.TypeName;
    t.DataContextPropertyName = t.TypeName;
    foreach(var k in t.ForeignKeys.Values)
    {
        k.MemberName = k.MemberName.StartsWith("Tbl") ? k.MemberName.Replace("Tbl","") : k.MemberName;
    }
}
GenerateModel();
```